# phpMyAdmin + nginx + Arch Linux = Can't proceed past login screen, advice wanted

Tags: mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin, webserver, broken-links

I am currently trying to setup a phpMyAdmin installation at a url like http://host.site.com/phpmyadmin, and I'm running into a few brick walls. Here's the details.

phpMyAdmin 3.4.9

Linux 3.1.7-1-ARCH (Arch Linux OS)

nginx 1.10.x

mySQL 5.0.90 (I think, don't quote me on that)

latest PHP available to Arch users (5.3.7)

What happens is that when I access my site's PMA installation, which in this example is going to be good.cakeisalie.com/phpMyAdmin, I get the usual PMA login screen that you enter your user name and password to logon to the SQL server.

HOWEVER. When I fill out the form, Firefox's loading circle spins, but then it takes me to some wacky url like this:

hxxp://good.cakeisalie.com/mnt/hd1/www/good.cakeisalie.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php?lang=en&token=d7177644eb3a22077864e89fc0da9c3b , **not** hxxp://good.cakeisalie.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php?lang=en&token=d7177644eb3a22077864e89fc0da9c3b . I am baffled by that issue, and I can't figure out what's going on.

Here is my nginx entry (stripped down to help find culprit parts):

```
server {
# UTF-8
charset utf-8;

# server name
server_name good.cakeisalie.com;
root /mnt/hd1/www/good.cakeisalie.com;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
# error_page 404 some.file;
# error_page 422 some.file;
# error_page 500 502 503 504 some.file;
# error_page 403 some.file;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
#     root           html;
include        fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /mnt/hd1/www/good.cakeisalie.com$fastcgi_script_name;
  if ($uri !~ "^/uploads/") {
  fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
  }
}
# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance if you can assist me with this issue!
- Cubeburner.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself.

Had to set $cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] to the right URL, so everything was smoothly operational.

I knew I was missing something simple. >_>